# HDFS not listening to port

Tags: hadoop, port, hdfs

Until yesterday I had a fully working Hadoop cluster running version 2.4.1, with YARN.

For some modifications I stopped the Hadoop cluster. After small modifications I tried restarting the cluster, but the HDFS listener never activated. I removed my small modifications and tried again with no luck. Now I have been going through all configurations for a day, trying to find out what is wrong. There is nothing interesting in the logs, except for processes telling me they cannot connect to that server&port. Command 'jps' shows that all is running (NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, DataNode).

I have deactivated all other nodes, trying to start HDFS only on the master node. Everything else should be as it was when the cluster/node worked perfectly.

My core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://my.internal.hostname:9000</value>
 <description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
my.internal.ip my.internal.hostname
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what modifications you did?

Comment: I was trying to add a new disk to one of the slaves. Mounted it, added to conf, tested, reverted, unmounted

Comment: It seems my namenode was replaying edit logs for quite a while, but now it has stopped doing that and nothing comes to its logs anymore. Namenode web interface is not up. So, problem persists.

Comment: tried accessing the namenode web interface using the ip address?

Comment: Funny thing is that the namenode web interface is working for some time while it replays edit logs, but it starts crashing after some json(?) length comes into play (some 50000 edit logs). After the operation is over, the web interface is fully down.
Noticed now in namenode logs that it complains about ´OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space´ when the replay process ends. Will continue with this.

Comment: try to set -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit and HADOOP_HEAPSIZE. check out this link : https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201850408-Namenode-fails-with-java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded.

Comment: Was unable to get the node working with any memory settings. I ended up copying the whole raw data to another new node and made that my master - seems to work fine. Thanks a lot sonic for help